# Save the result of setPredicate to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nspredicate

I have created  NSPredicate to search  the string in my coredata. 
so in this case does anyone know how to save the result `[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];` in NSString.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                  mytext];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: `setPredicate:` doesn't return anything. Could you explicit your question? A sample?

Comment: Hi @Larme,  I have the result  [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; so I want to save that result in NSString.

Comment: You have to explain, how a fetch result can be a string. Entities are fetched, not strings and not one is fetched, but potentially N.

Comment: The result of search in fetch it gives the result of string that contain or not.  so if it contains it shows the the result of contain one in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write Your Table Name in `@"YOUR_ENTITY_NAME"`

Make sure that your table contains `name` column

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"YOUR_ENTITY_NAME"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", mytext]];
NSMutableArray *arrResult = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@", arrResult); //output
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
NSArray *fetchedObjects;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"your entity"  inManagedObjectContext: context];
[fetch setEntity:entityDescription];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", mytext]];
NSError * error = nil;
fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

if([fetchedObjects count] == 1)
NSLog(@"%@",[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: HI @lyankar,  unfortunately it crash and the message: I'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate

Comment: What exactly fetch request here [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

Comment: Thanks @lyankar and Nirav Kotecha.